# Mono Compiler as Service or Microsoft Roselyn for a vb parser

Tags: compiler-construction, mono, roslyn

i want to analyze vb code with a parse like roselyn or mcs, but i want to do it with 
c sharp but the code i want to analyze is in vb code.

I have seen that in both frameworks, you can pass the code and gives you the syntax tree, but
for example if your writting it in c sharp, it can parser visual basic code?

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(@"Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text

Namespace HelloWorld

    Module Program
       
        Sub Main(args As String())
      
            Console.WriteLine(“Hello, World!”)
     
        End Sub
  
     End Module

End Namespace");
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
```

My question is if the can be done with the mcs from mono or with microsoft roslyn?

Comment: Use SyntaxTree.ParseText if you're using the 2012CTP as ParseCompilationUnit has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. You just need to use types from the namespace `Roslyn.Compilers.VisualBasic` (in the assembly with the same name) instead of types from `Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp`.